# rapidjson Schema Document multiple roots error

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I am using RapidJSON to parse JSON files. I am trying to use a `rapidjson::SchemaDocument` to make a JSON schema to validate received JSON files.

But, when I try to construct a schema document that was generated by website [liquid-technologies.com](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-json-to-schema-converter), "error code 2" is received, which indicates that the JSON (schema) document I am trying to parse has multiple roots, even though it has only one.

Here is the schema document I am trying to parse:

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "title": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "pay": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "country": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "employer": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "workforce": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "officelocation": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "name",
        "workforce",
        "officelocation"
      ]
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "flexibleHours": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "title",
    "pay",
    "country",
    "employer",
    "location",
    "flexibleHours",
    "description"
  ]
}
```

And here is my code:

```cpp
std::string schemaJson = readFile("../jsonschemas/postjobschema.json");
    rapidjson::Document sd;
    if (sd.Parse(schemaJson.c_str()).HasParseError()) {
        std::cout << "Schema has parse errors" << std::endl;
        if (sd.GetParseError() == rapidjson::kParseErrorDocumentRootNotSingular)
            std::cout << "There are multiple roots" << std::endl;
    }
```

Is my schema incorrect, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you schema is correct, but there is something wrong with your code.

I have tested your scehma json and a mock input json with rapidjson's [`example/schemavalidator`](https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson/blob/master/example/schemavalidator/schemavalidator.cpp), it turns out everything works well.

input.json:

```json
{
    "title": "foo",
    "pay": 100,
    "country": "US",
    "employer": { "name": "bar", "workforce": 12, "officelocation": "UK"},
    "location": "CA",
    "flexibleHours": true,
    "description": "hello"
}
```

```sh
./bin/schemavalidator /tmp/schema.json < /tmp/input.json

Input JSON is valid.
```

Would you like to read your schema json file with `rapidjson::FileReadStream`?

```cpp
    // Read a JSON schema from file into Document
    Document d;
    char buffer[4096];

    {
        FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if (!fp) {
            printf("Schema file '%s' not found\n", argv[1]);
            return -1;
        }
        FileReadStream fs(fp, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        d.ParseStream(fs);
        if (d.HasParseError()) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Schema file '%s' is not a valid JSON\n", argv[1]);
            fprintf(stderr, "Error(offset %u): %s\n",
                static_cast<unsigned>(d.GetErrorOffset()),
                GetParseError_En(d.GetParseError()));
            fclose(fp);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
```

Comment: I can't believe it. It is exactly as you said. It turns out my readFile function retrieves an extra space after the input, so the last character in the output string is always a whitespace. I suspected that my readFile function is not perfect, but I did not expect that RapidJSON would fail because of an extra space! It turns out, it's not just RapidJSON, but SQLite too, which I am using.
Anyways, thank you very much.